# Responsive design for elements

Tags: css, responsive-design

How can I make an element with class properties display as `inline-block` for laptops and desktops and a list for tablets and mobiles?

Whenever I shrink the width of my browser, iPad design elements do not fit properly.

```css
.properties {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  .properties {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .propertyButton {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .properties {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .propertyButton {
    margin-top: -2%;
    margin-left: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="propertyWrapper" style="width:100%;">
  <div style="float:right">
    <span ng-click="addProperty()" class="button buttonPrimary pull-right">Add Property</span>
  </div>
  <div class="properties">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="properties">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="properties">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="properties">
    <label>
      IsRequired(TE):
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="property.TradeEarthRequired" name="UsedEquipmentPropertyList[0].TradeEarthRequired" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  </div>
  <div class="propertyButton">
    <span class="button primaryAction" ng-click="addProperty()">Add</span>
    <span class="button primaryAction" ng-click="removeProperty(property,$index)">Delete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot, or other visual clarification? I do not believe I understand the issue fully.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you just need to duplicate the code.
Keep an inline-block view for windows sized over 1200.
When you are under 1200, just hide it and show a fresh new list ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just got your CSS a bit wrong - the media queries shouldn't be nested like that, as far as I can tell. Is [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr5v7xs5/2/) more like what you wanted?

```
.properties {
    display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .properties {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .propertyButton {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .properties {
        display: list-item;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .propertyButton {
        margin-top:-2%;
        margin-left: 30%;
    }
}
```

Comment: somewhat similar to . However for scree between 500 and 780 I need a table like display. Two column layout